# Why can't deflate (zlib) compress two identical strings concatenated together?

Tags: gzip, zlib, deflate, compression

Or more accurately stated, when two identical strings are concatenated to each other, why can't zlib deflate the *entire* second string?  It seems that when a matching string starts immediately after the previous instance of the same string, zlib emits the first character as a string literal and then emits a backwards reference to the previous string minus the first character.

For example, if I use zlib to deflate the string *latelate*, the output is 5 string literals followed by a back reference...

```
l a t e l <len=3, dist=4>
```

or huffman encoded...

```
0000000 cb 49 2c 49 cd 01 62 00
0000010
```

where I've simplified the output by using a "raw" deflate stream (i.e. windowBits = -15) and the fixed huffman encoding (i.e. the compression strategy is Z_FIXED).

Why must zlib emit the second literal character 'l' before using a back reference to "ate"?

In other words, why can't it output...?

```
l a t e <len=4, dist=4>
```

I tried forcing the second version with my own deflate implementation, but zlib won't inflate the output.  I get the error *"invalid or incomplete deflate data"*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's separate DEFLATE, as a compression bitstream format described in https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1951.txt from zlib, which is implementation of algorithms to encode and decode such bitstream.

Then, DEFLATE certainly can represent, and compress, concatenation of 2 strings. Why zlib doesn't do that? Well, because match searching for LZ77 compression is inherently heuristic task, so some choices won't be explored, even those which seem obvious to a human.

Using a trivial hash-based LZ77 encoder, double-string case is easily found:

```
L6c # l
L61 # a
L74 # t
L65 # e
C-4,4
```

And this sequence can be encoded with static zlib encoding without problem, result is:

```
CB 49 2C 49 05 61 00
```

This bitstream also can be decoded without problem by zlib. You can try that using Python:

```
import zlib
import binascii
zlib.decompress(binascii.unhexlify("CB492C49056100"), -15)
```

So, what version of zlib did you use? Maybe it was too old?

Comment: Thx. I must have made a mistake encoding the string by hand. I checked your encoding and it decompressed just fine.

Comment: Ironically, I made the same argument in the introduction of my own [Internet Draft for an alternative token-based deflate algorithm](http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-morgan-ezflate-00) :) ...

_RFC 1951 explicitly states that the "deflate" format is not tied to any particular algorithm. To quote, it says, "While it is the intent of this document to define the 'deflate' compressed data format without reference to any particular compression algorithm, the format is related to the compressed formats produced by LZ77 ... [however] a compressor need not follow it in order to be compliant."_